# How can I grant PROCESS privilege to a user?

Tags: mysql

I have a user called `test`, and I want to grant `process` privilege to him.

So far, I have tried:

```
grant process on *.* to test; 
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

then, I show all grants for user `test` by running:

```
show grants for test@'%';
```

the result does contain a `PROCESS' line like:

> GRANT PROCESS ON *.* TO 'test'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD ...
>
> ...
>
> ...

But it didn't appear to work for user `test`.

So, how can I grant PROCESS privilege to a user?

Answer (score 20):

```
GRANT PROCESS,SELECT ON *.* ...
```

Comment: The full line for dummies like me who has to look for it is `GRANT PROCESS, SELECT ON dbname.* TO 'username@localhost';` You may need to change the "localhost" part for an ip or wherever your user authenticates from

Comment: When trying to set PROCESS privileges on a specific database, I got an error 
```ERROR 1221 (HY000): Incorrect usage of DB GRANT and GLOBAL PRIVILEGES```


Seems this privilege is global, and can not be set on a specific database, so it's solved by running it without database specification:


```GRANT PROCESS ON *.* TO 'username@localhost'```

Answer (score -14):

```
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON mydb.* TO 'myuser'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Or Try

```
CREATE USER 'newuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'newuser'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

than Run

```
SELECT User FROM mysql.user;
```

you will find the User created by you, if you want to see Privileges of all users than run

```
SELECT * FROM mysql.user;
```

Finally to see Grant Information try

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.user_privileges;
```

Comment: Excuse me if I am mistaken, but "ALL PRIVILEGES" is *all permissions* right? Not just `PROCESS`, which is what the question asked for